# Overlapped, multiple images in a responsive container

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive container and one image within it. It works good. The container and the image are resizing when the window-size changes. But, I need not only one, but **more images** which exactly **overlap** each other (all of them have the same size). How can I achieve this with HTML and CSS?

```css
.pageCenter {
  display: block;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  float: none;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.imageContainer img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
}

img {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageCenter">
  <div class="imageContainer">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/nature" style="width:100%;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use display:inline-block and arrange imgs parallel.

Comment: What do you mean by overlap exactly? on top covering one another? Or only partially covering? Can you draw a picture of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Can you show me the exact code?

Comment: @Michael: they cover each other. All of them have the same coordinates.

Comment: If images are same size or same proportion it is enaugh to set `min-width: 100%;  position: absolute` for images. And for .imageContainer position: can't be static. Z-index will decide which image is on top.

Comment: GUYS, please show me the solution BASED ON MY CODE above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `grid` in order to specify what `row` and `column` you want all images to sit in. They will then overlap and adjust to your container (do note the images I am using are all the same picture, but if you inspect, the 3 images are on-top of eachother:

```css
.pageCenter {
  display: block;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  float: none;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.imageContainer{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageCenter">
  <div class="imageContainer">
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/800/400" style="width:100%;" />
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/800/400" style="width:100%;" />
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/800/400" style="width:100%;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that `grid` isn't supported by all [old browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid)

Comment: Mike, it works as a DREAM! Thank you for this perfect solution! Also, thank you everyone who dealt with my question.

Comment: Just want to say that `display:grid` is probably the most awesome discovery I've made and this along with `margin:auto auto` on your img gives you a LOT of responsiveness and flexibility.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.imageContainer {
  position:relative;
}

.imageContainer .img-1 {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.imageContainer .img-2 {
  float:left;
}

.clearfix {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageCenter">
    <div class="imageContainer">
         <img src="https://wow.olympus.eu/webfile/img/1632/x=1024/oly_testwow_stage.jpg" class="img-1" />
         <img src="https://wow.olympus.eu/webfile/img/1632/x=1024/oly_testwow_stage.jpg" class="img-1" />
         <img src="https://wow.olympus.eu/webfile/img/1632/x=1024/oly_testwow_stage.jpg" class="img-1" />
         <img src="https://wow.olympus.eu/webfile/img/1632/x=1024/oly_testwow_stage.jpg" class="img-2" />            
         <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to set the parent to position:relative; and the images (.child) to position:absolute;

Updated with images, they overlap.

Updated again with your code.

Update #3: You need to set one image to position:absolute and one to float and add a clearfix element.

Comment: This caused me a column (image below image), not overlap.

Comment: can you modify MY CODE shown above? For me wasn't overlap.

Comment: Marcel: it is not good, because the images extend beyond the container. I need the proper container. With my original code the container surrounds the image.

Comment: I did it with 4 images, 3. and 4. got .imageContainer .img-3 {
  float:left;
} and .imageContainer .img-4 {
  float:left;
} Now 3 images are in a column. What should I do with the 3. and 4.? 1. and 2. are overlapped, but 3. and 4. not.

Comment: Give 3 of 4 images the .img-1 class and one image the .img-2 class. This should make it work.

Comment: Marcel: this works perfectly! Guys, I got 2 perfect solutions, you are fantastic! Thank you very much!

Comment: I did, but my reputation is 14 instead of minimal required 15, so my vote is ignored ... :( Maybe, I open a new question, it will increase my rep.